# How to debug nvim-lspconfig neovim plugin?

Tags: neovim, clangd, nvim-lspconfig, neovim-plugin

I'm using the neovim plugin nvim-lspconfig setup with clangd server and a generated compile_commands.json file for C++ development.  vim.lsp.buf.definition (go to definition) works most of the time, but does not work for some symbols.  Any tips on how to figure out what's wrong or see what's going on under the hood?

I tried "set verbose=15" and looking at the runtime log but do not see anything useful.

Comment: The logs which are useful to look at are the language server's `stderr`. I'm not sure how to get that for neovim, maybe you can ask in the plugin's issue tracker. Once you have the logs, please feel free to edit your question to include them, or file an issue https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues and attach it there.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I believe [this](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1666) is my same issue, the symbols not resolving seem to be all template arg types.

Comment: The linked issue only affects "find references" (and "rename"), not "go to definition". If you're seeing an issue with "go to definition", the underlying cause is something different.